# What is the wording on outline of Wright Flyer on FAA pilot license?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification

I was told once that the outline of the Wright Flyer was taken from a speech given by the Wright Brothers.  In the picture below you can very clearly see the words on the Wright Flyer.  Does anybody know what that speech was?

[image: FAA Pilots Certificate front side] 
Picture taken from [Wikipedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Private_Pilot.jpg)

[image: FAA Pilots Certificate back side]
Picture taken from [Keven's Aviation Adventure](http://kevensaviationadventure.blogspot.com/)

[image: An easier view of what's being discussed]

Comment: Due to this question, I also learned from someone that the flip side of this type of certificate also has micro print on the shirt collars of the Wright brothers and the depiction of the Wright Flyer on that side. Perhaps you should edit this question to encompass all of that too.  I'd ask it, but I think it's better to keep it together.  What does the flip-side say?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> "Without question, flight is represented by countless heroes who have stirred greatness in others. It was a dream that had been waiting to be realized for thousands of years, and chased by countless visionaries, scholars and brave souls. But even as the mass of collected knowledge came to a crucial turning point, it was not until the ingenuity of the Wright Brothers that the puzzle of powered flight was solved. Discovery requires deep understanding, constant interpretation of knowledge and unbridled persistence."

It is part of a speech given by [Marion Blakey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marion_Blakey) on December 17, 2002 at the Air and Space Museum for the Centennial of Flight Kick-Off event. Unfortunately I can't find the full text of the speech (for free at least, it is part of a [book you can buy for \$5 used, or \$108 new](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824210247)). Marion Blakey was the 15th FAA Administrator from 2002 to 2007.

Comment: What part of the plane are the words depicting?  I'm wanting to say stringers, but I know that's internal.  Would they be called struts?

Comment: The words make up the vertical (struts would be my guess) supports between the upper wing and the lower wing.