# What are some of the easter eggs on the FAA pilot license?

Tags: pilot-certification

I know that the back of the card has a [hidden speech](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29836/what-is-the-wording-on-outline-of-wright-flyer-on-faa-pilot-license?newreg=eb357719908a40d78452c09b4f5d26a9) along the Wright brother's collars and the Wright flyer's frame. Also, if you shine a black light on the card, there's an (invisible to the naked eye) imbued text that reads "FLY SAFE". Are there any other easter eggs to be found?

Comment: Those aren't "easter eggs," they're anti-counterfeiting features.

Comment: Are there any other anti-counterfeiting features? I know there's also the FAA hologram thing on the front as well.